# Can Windows 7 enable Folder Redirection via Group Policy?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, folder-redirection

I'd like to enable folder redirection on my stand-alone Windows 7 Pro box. Is that possible?

The Group Policy Editor shown in the [Managing Roaming User Data Deployment Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766489%28WS.10%29.aspx) has a *Folder Redirection* node that I don't see:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is that possible?

Short answer, No.

You can't "Roam" on a single box.. you need a domain dude.

The "Redirection" is to another server, so your profile gets copied down to your box on login, really damn handy if your machine craps out, cause then you just log into another box, download your profile, and your working again!

[Related](https://superuser.com/questions/80622/folder-redirection-doesnt-work-in-windows-7-or-vista)

Answer (score 0):

While you can't set Folder Redirection for a single box via the Group Policy editor (hence "Group"), you can set the folder locations from the registry, in the [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders] key.

For a single box, I imagine you just want Folder Redirection for its backup or extensibility purposes.

Comment: That did not work for me. I also had to change the location in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders".